# Palo Alto Globalprotect - connect via cmd

Tags: vpn, powershell, windows-command-prompt, palo-alto-networks

Scenario: Windows box having the Palo Alto Globalprotect vpn client installed.

Is it possible to use commandline or powershell to connect the vpn client to a remote host?

I know this is possible with other vpn clients but can't find any documentation for the Palo Alto one.

Any help is appreciated..

Comment: You might be able to configure the VPN client settings so that it would connect automatically: https://www.paloaltonetworks.com/documentation/80/globalprotect/globalprotect-admin-guide/globalprotect-clients/deploy-agent-settings-transparently/customizable-agent-settings

I have never done this myself, but I do have systems that auto-connect using a certificate with Global Protect.

Comment: Did you have any luck working this out?